# JqPlot + MVC Data from ViewModel - Is this possible?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I will be short.

I have a view that will plot a Heart Rate chart based on some information provided on the ViewModel.

This is the line that calls the JqPlot chart in my view (scripts section):

```
@section scripts
{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/charting")
    <script>            
        $.jqplot('HeartInformation', [[@string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(h=> h.HeartRate))]]);
    </script>
}
```

This is the DIV in the same view, where i want the graph to be appended:

```
 <div id="HeartInformation" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
```

As you can see, there is a collection of laps that have a collection of trackpoints (where the HR are)

The problem is that I can't see the graph. I made a test and JQPlot is working fine.

I also tried this (adding -> ' but didn't work as well) :

```
    $.jqplot('HeartInformation', [['@string.Join(",", Model.Activity.Laps.SelectMany(t => t.TrackPoints).Select(h=> h.HeartRate))']]);
```

But no results. Is the problem that the view calls the jqPlot before the data series is written? I checked the page source code and seems ok:

```
        $.jqplot('HeartInformation', [[106,106,104,105,108,111,159,160,160,160,161,160,160,160,160,159,158,158,157,158,158,157,158,157,158,158,159,160,161,162,163,163,164,164,165,164,164,164,164,165,165,165,166,166,168,169,169,169,170,171,172]]);
```

Any ideas?

***Now it's working. I moved the div out of some heavy nested html structure and now I can see the plot. The thing is where the DIV was originally the widht was somehow narrow for it, I moved it outside and now I see it. Weird. Thanks for your help!***

Comment: if you hardcode that same page source that calls jqplot does it show? Does your div is called HeartInformation or HearthInformation? http://jsfiddle.net/hFVnv/

Comment: can you post the relevant html of the page as well? And have you included all of the relevant css and js files for jqplot?

Comment: @NerdFury there you have more contextual information. Everything seems fine..

Comment: Here the basic case you present does create the plot chart. http://jsfiddle.net/LX7KS/1/

Comment: @Ernesto the problem is that in my view there is no chart... I don't know if the series (numbers) are added after the plot request (due to being written from the model...) I don't know.

Comment: Now it's working. I moved the div out of some heavy nested html structure and now I can see the plot. The thing is where the DIV was originally the widht was somehow narrow for it, I moved it outside and now I see it. Weird. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it got solved. Btw, the data rendered from the model is already there before any javascript executes. Even before leaving the server side.